# Angular route resolve for sessionStorage login variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, resolve

I've built a login system using Angular JS. When the user logs in, a session storage variable is set and they are redirected to a dashboard page (should only be accessible when logged in)"

```
$window.sessionStorage["isLoggedIn"] = true;
$location.path("/dashboard");
```

Now I want to use resolve on my any routes that required the user to be logged in. I find the documentation for this very confusing and can't understand it. If the user is not logged in and tries to access one of these pages, they need to be shown a message saying they can't access that page.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
    templateUrl : "framework/views/dashboard.html",
    controller  : "DashboardCtrl",
    title: "Dashboard",
    resolve: {
      //how does this work?!
    }
});


app.factory("loginCheckService", function(){
  //check sessionStorage and return?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would rather listern for locationChangeStart event, perform validations (auth), prevent the route change (if required) and raise some events (unauthroized) to show the login form.

something like

```
app.run(function($rootScope,LoginService){
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event){
          if(!LoginService.isUserLoggedIn()){
            event.preventDefault();
             //LoginService.raiseUserNotLoggedIn();  OR
                 $rootScope.$broadcast('UserNotLoggedIn');
         }

      });
  });

app.controller('LoginFormController',function($scope){
    $scope.userLoggedIn=true;
    $scope.on('UserNotLoggedIn',function(){
          $scope.userLoggedIn=false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve allows you to define a set of tasks that will execute before the route is loaded. It is essential just a set of keys and functions, which allow you to do things like asynchronous http requests, run code snippets, set values, etc (really whatever you want), prior to page load.

So if you had a service that made a http get request and returned a promise to ensure a session exists on  the server each time a route occurs, resolve guarantees that it will not load the page until the http request is fulfilled, and the promise is a success.  In other words if the fulfilled promise fails the page will not load:

```
.config([ '$routeProvider', function( $routeProvide ) {

    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'framework/views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'dashCtrl',
        resolve: {
            DateOfBirth: ['Date', function( Date ) {  // random example of other uses for resolve
                return Date.getCurrentYear() - 37;
            }],
            AuthUser: ['$q', '$location', 'UserSession', 

                function( $q, $location, UserSession) {
                    return UserSession.getSession()

                    .then(function( success ) {  // server response 200 = OK
                       // if you are in here the promise has succeeded and 
                       // the page will load

                       // can do whatever you want

                       return success
                    }, function( error ) { // server response not 200 = Not OK

                       // if you are in here the promise has failed and 
                       // the page will not load

                       // can do whatever you want                         

                       // if unauthenticated typically you'd:
                       $location.path('/login);
                       $location.replace();

                       // for this read up on promises, but promises can be 
                       // chained, and it says move me to next error promise
                       // in the chain. if you don't use this it will assume
                       // the error was handled and pass you to the next 
                       // success in chain.  So good practice even if you're 
                       // not chaining
                       return $q.reject( error );
                    });
        }];
        }
    })
}]);
```

Another nice thing about resolve is the keys are injectable. So you can pass the result to your controller:

```
.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['AuthUser', 'UserSession', 'DateOfBirth' 
    function(AuthUser, UserSession, DateOfBirth) {

    // show all the errors you want by accessing the AuthUser 
    // data contained in the server response, or just read the 
    // server response status

    var self = this;

    self.status = AuthUser.status;
    self.response = AuthUser.data;
}]);
```

Then in your UI you can ngShow or ngBind blah blah on the result using dashCtrl.response or dashCtrl.status, or whatever you decide on doing with the resolved data, and show your errors knowing the page never loaded.

I'd suggest that on route you check the session instead of storing it on the client.  Also, keep in mind the resolve only works on routes, but if you're making calls to the server that don't require routing you'll want to look up how to use interceptors.  They allow you to peak at the outgoing and incoming server requests/responses unrelated to routing, so those which occur while you're currently on a specific page like /dashboard/home that don't trigger a route, and just simply update /home content.

Comment: Let me know if something doesn't make sense